# Grails 2.5.0 - Use Asset Pipeline to use createLink in .js file?

Tags: grails, asset-pipeline

I'm looking to add a "Do you want to log out?" dialog that pops up before the session ends, and the user can click OK to ping the site and not get automatically logged out.

To code this, I would ideally only like to add a `<asset:javascript src="session.logout.dialog.js" />` into the layout.

The issue in only including a .js file is that I need links to controllers in the JavaScript file. I'm not aware of a way to code the links without some kind of initialization code in the gsp such as `initLogoutDialog("${createLink(...)}")`. Does the Asset Pipeline plugin allow me a way to bypass the normal restrictions and use createLink as if it were a gsp?

Comment: I didn't understand your question . Are you trying to upload a file which should be loaded at runtime at your upload request ?

Comment: I read over the question and realized it was unclear. I've reworded it.

Comment: if you are trying to inject the controller&action link into the js file, then i don't believe asset pipeline can help here, but i might be wrong.

Comment: I updated the question again. I'm really just looking to at gsp code (or some way to make a link) in a .js file.

Comment: try this -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11037614/pass-javascript-variable-into-createlink-method-call-grails

Comment: That works, but for now I'll just initialize the JavaScript files after including the .js file.